# not able to centre tikz picture

Tags: diagrams

For the undermentioned tikz picture, I am not able to place it in centre. May kindly help.

```
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=black!10]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]

\node (start) [startstop] {Preparation of Tensile Specimen};
\node (in1) [startstop] [below of=start, xshift=0cm] {Tensile Testing};
\node (in2) [startstop] [below of=in1, xshift=0cm] {Analysis of Tensile Test Data for Sy};
\node (in3) [startstop] [below of=in2, xshift=0cm] {Preparation of High Cycle Fatigue Specimen};
\node (in4) [startstop] [below of=in3, xshift=0cm] {High Cycle Fatigue Testing};
\node (stop) [startstop] [below of=in4, xshift=0cm] {Analysis of Test Data};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (in2);
\draw [arrow] (in2) -- (in3);
\draw [arrow] (in3) -- (in4);
\draw [arrow] (in4) -- (stop);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I have no problem with your code. It is your margins that certainly prevent you from centering in the page. Give a complete minimal example to see what bothers you.

Answer (score 1):

If your picture is outside a float environment (e.g., a figure), make sure you add `\noindent` then `\makebox[\textwidth]{ .. }` will center the image irrespective of how wide the margins are.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
center
\end{center}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=black!10]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
\node (start) [startstop] {Preparation of Tensile Specimen};
\node (in1) [startstop] [below of=start, xshift=0cm] {Tensile Testing};
\node (in2) [startstop] [below of=in1, xshift=0cm] {Analysis of Tensile Test Data for Sy};
\node (in3) [startstop] [below of=in2, xshift=0cm] {Preparation of High Cycle Fatigue Specimen};
\node (in4) [startstop] [below of=in3, xshift=0cm] {High Cycle Fatigue Testing};
\node (stop) [startstop] [below of=in4, xshift=0cm] {Analysis of Test Data};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (in2);
\draw [arrow] (in2) -- (in3);
\draw [arrow] (in3) -- (in4);
\draw [arrow] (in4) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you soooo much Sir! Your prompt effort made my life so simple. Kindly help as to how I can add a caption & label to the above outline. Regards

Comment: Just use this code: `\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
..
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{fig:mypic}
\end{figure}`

Answer (score 1):

since a way, how is your picture included in document, unknown, it is not possible to advise you what to do. anyway, see if the following redesign of your picture and their including in document can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning}  
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[htb]
   \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, fill=black!10,
                text width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center,
                on chain, join=by arr},
   arr/.style = {thick, -Stealth}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style = {box}]
\node (start)   {Preparation of Tensile Specimen};
\node (in1)     {Tensile Testing};
\node (in2)     {Analysis of Tensile Test Data for Sy};
\node (in3)     {Preparation of High Cycle Fatigue Specimen};
\node (in4)     {High Cycle Fatigue Testing};
\node (stop)    {Analysis of Test Data};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Flowchart \dots}
    \label{fig:flowchart}
    \centering
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

- if you prefer to have text in nodes only in one line, than replace `text width=3cm` with `minimum width=3cm`.
- in mwe above i use libraries `arrows. meta`, `chains` and its macro `join=by ...` and positioning. with their use code become shorter and concise.
- in a case, that this image is complete (no other nodes, nor connection between them), than you can omit all nodes names and by this make its code even shorter.

**edit:**
added  cation to figure as well new code example considering above comments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, fill=black!10,
                 minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center,
                on chain, join=by arr},
   arr/.style = {thick, -Stealth}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style = {box}]
\node   {Preparation of Tensile Specimen};
\node   {Tensile Testing};
\node   {Analysis of Tensile Test Data for Sy};
\node   {Preparation of High Cycle Fatigue Specimen};
\node   {High Cycle Fatigue Testing};
\node   {Analysis of Test Data};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Flowchart \dots}
    \label{fig:flowchart}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```